# Why do we need to define a static variable of a class, unlike the other member of a class?

Tags: c++, oop

Whenever we have a class with some static member variable, why do we need to define it?

Why can't we use it directly?

I wanted to see if any memory space would be allocated to the static variable if I don't define it, so I wrote this little code and it seems like memory is indeed allocated for the variable.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A
{
    public:
    int a;
    static int b;
};
// int A::b = 1;
int main() 
{
    cout<<sizeof(A::b);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
4
```

Now, I defined the variable and initialized it (uncommented the **int A::b = 1;** line) and ran the same code, even this time the output was the same.

So, what is the purpose behind defining it?

Comment: `sizeof(A::b)` doesn't tell you anything about whether memory has been allocated for the variable. It's just telling you the size of an `int`. After all, you could have done `cout << sizeof(A);` without creating an instance of an `A`, and you definitely didn't allocate memory for one.

Comment: So, we do the defining to give a real memory space to it, right?

Comment: Other members of the class (I assume you mean non-static data) exist inside every object you create. Whereas there is only ever supposed to be one static data member in the entire program, even if you never create n instance. So where should it be put? The definition in namespace scope is the answer to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For static data member you have to allocate memory for it in your implementation, what you are doing now does not allocate memory but you are just getting the size of the `int`.
In C++ 17 you can declare static variable inline, for `int` its default value is zero but you can set any value you want. Like this:

```
 static inline int b=4;
```

Answer (score 2):

The definition is required if the variable is [odr-used](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#One_Definition_Rule), while `sizeof(A::b)` doesn't.

> One and only one definition of every non-inline function or variable that is [*odr-used*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#ODR-use) (see below) is required to appear in the entire program (including any standard and user-defined libraries). The compiler is not required to diagnose this violation, but the behavior of the program that violates it is undefined.

For example, if you take address of the variable, then it's odr-used and it must be defined.

```
cout << &A::b;
```